# Select Query Optimization on MySQL for Huge Data

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization, union

## MySql Server 5.5, Database engine MyIsam, Table fact_transaction is indexed on date_key, time_key, unit_cost_price, unit_retail_price (combined key) and same for fact_stockout_sales excluding time_key.##

[Query plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA6D5.jpg)

[image: Query plan]

Query

```
SELECT 
    t.Level, t.Name, t.KeyValue, 
    ROUND( (SUM(t.Gross)/SUM(t.Revenue))*100, 2 ) AS Value, 
    ROUND( (SUM(t.adjustedGross)/SUM(t.adjustedRevenue))*100, 2 ) AS adjustedValue,
    t.dataType AS dataType 
FROM 
   (SELECT "item" AS Level, ds.product_name AS Name, ds.product_id AS KeyValue, 
        SUM(ft.gross_profit) AS Gross, 
        SUM(ft.selling_amount) AS Revenue, 
        SUM(ft.adjusted_gross_profit) AS adjustedGross, 
        SUM(ft.adjusted_selling_amount) AS adjustedRevenue,
        "%" AS dataType 
    FROM fact_transaction AS ft 
    JOIN dim_sku AS ds ON ft.sku_key = ds.sku_key 
    WHERE ft.date_key BETWEEN 20080215 AND 20130107 
      AND ft.time_key BETWEEN 100 AND 235900 
      AND ft.unit_cost_price BETWEEN 0 AND 1333 
      AND ft.unit_retail_price BETWEEN 0 AND 16500 
      AND ft.store_key IN ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16") 
      AND ds.product_id IN (1312009,1312007,... Huge List say 30000) 
      AND ds.category IN ("Male","Female","Unisex") 
      AND ft.day_of_week IN ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7") 
      AND ds.collection_name IN ("Base","SS12","AW12") 
    GROUP BY ds.product_id                          
    UNION 
    SELECT "item" AS Level, ds.product_name AS Name, ds.product_id AS KeyValue, 
        SUM(ft.gross_profit) AS Gross, 
        SUM(ft.selling_amount) AS Revenue, 
        SUM(ft.adjusted_gross_profit) AS adjustedGross, 
        SUM(ft.adjusted_selling_amount) AS adjustedRevenue, 
        "%" AS dataType 
    FROM fact_stockout_sales AS ft 
    JOIN dim_sku AS ds ON ft.sku_key = ds.sku_key 
    WHERE ft.date_key BETWEEN 20080215 AND 20130107 
      AND ft.unit_cost_price BETWEEN 0 AND 1333 
      AND ft.unit_retail_price BETWEEN 0 AND 16500 
      AND ft.store_key IN ("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16") 
      AND ds.product_id IN (1312009,1312007,.. Huge List say 30000) 
      AND ds.category IN ("Male","Female","Unisex") 
      AND ft.day_of_week IN ("1","2","3","4","5","6","7") 
      AND ds.collection_name IN ("Base","SS12","AW12") 
      GROUP BY ds.product_id) AS t 
GROUP BY t.KeyValue
```

Comment: Why do you use UNION to combine two **identic** queries ? This must be slow - the same query is running twice, then UNION combines two identic resultsets end eliminates duplicates.

Comment: @kordirko: They're not identical. They're selecting from two different tables, and the second omits ft.time_key from the WHERE clause.

Comment: Righ, they are not the same. But since both subqueries contain join to the same table `dim_sku`, you might try to transform this query using "join factorization" to avoid scaning `dim_sk` twice, this link describes how this transformation works: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e15858/tgsql_transform.htm#BABHGGEG

Comment: @Kordirko Thanks for the link I will look into it. My doubt is even though the combined index is detected it is not actually using it. Look at the attached query plan. How to enforce to use index

Answer (score 0):

1. Measure time to run.
2. Measure time to run for each query that's part of the UNION operator.
3. Index every column used in a WHERE clause.
4. Put the most selective columns first in the WHERE clause, and test the effect of multi-column indexes.
5. Cut useless tests. (Surely ft.day_of_week can be removed from the WHERE clauses.)
6. Reconsider your data types. Are the days of the week and store keys *really* strings?
7. Reconsider the decision to select five years of data at a time.
8. Try moving product id numbers to a temporary table, and joining on it.

Comment: 1.Date,time,costPrice,retailPrice are most predominant colmns that is why it appears immediately after where.
2.day_of_week, store_id,product_id's datatype is integers only. 
3.Combined Indx is being done for the predominant columns (data,time,costPrice,retailPrice)
4.The query i pasted is the exact query except product_id check coz the list it gonna check is huge.

Comment: *Predominant* and *selective* don't mean the same thing in English. You want to build a compound index on *selective* columns that are used in the WHERE clause. My comment about the exact query was my mistake--I thought there were mismatched parens.